# ScalarsConverterFactory en mal estado

Tags: android, android-studio

el ScalarsConverterFactory me sale Cannot resolve symbol 'ScalarsConverterFactory' y no entiendo el por que de ello si importe todo lo que tenia que importar para que Retrofit funcione adecuadamente.

```
private void get_Clientes(int getBodegasCodigo) {
        getClienteName.clear();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ApiOpenPanelCaptel.URL_api).addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()).build();
        ApiOpenPanelCaptel apiOpenPanelCaptel = retrofit.create(ApiOpenPanelCaptel.class);
        Call<String> call = apiOpenPanelCaptel.getClientes(getBodegasCodigo);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    Log.i("Response", response.body());
                } else {
                    Log.i("Response", "Response body is null");
                }
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        Log.i("Success", response.body().toString());
                        try {
                            String getResponse = response.body().toString();
                            getClienteData = new ArrayList<Clientes>();
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getResponse);
                            getClienteData.add(new Clientes(-1, -1, "--Selecione cliente--"));
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                Clientes clientes = new Clientes();
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                clientes.setReferencia(jsonObject.getInt("referencia"));
                                clientes.setBodega(jsonObject.getInt("bodega"));
                                clientes.setNombre(jsonObject.getString("nombre"));
                                getClienteData.add(clientes);
                            }
                            for (int i = 0; i < getClienteData.size(); i++) {
                                getClienteName.add(getClienteData.get(i).getNombre().toString());
                            }
                            ArrayAdapter<String> spClientessAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(FormularioRellenar.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getClienteName);
                            spClientessAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            ClienteAfectado.setAdapter(spClientessAdapter);
                            //si se quiere crear un filtro respecto a los valores seleccionados en Clientes.
                            ClienteAfectado.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (JSONException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

aca igual dejo los import

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
```

realmente ya no entiendo el por que si el interface esta bueno y todo lo que es las clases igual y la api es identica a la modelo de la clase la cual quiero ocupar en la app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si obtienes el error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'ScalarsConverterFactory'

indica que la clase no existe en tu proyecto, para esto debes asegurar que usas el `import` necesario si la clase es del Android sdk, o en este caso si la clase no es del SDK de Android debes asegurar agregar la correcta dependencia.

En este caso revisando el [proyecto Java Scalars Converter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/scalars), indica que debes agregar la siguiente dependencia [definiendo la versión](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/converter-scalars/2.9.0/versions), en tu archivo  `build.gradle` que se encuentra dentro del directorio `/app`

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0'
```

Sincronizas los archivos `build.gradle` con tu proyecto y deberá funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

por alguna razon
´´´
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.*'])
´´´

eso lo arreglo todo.

Comment: te sugiero no leer desde /libs el .jar, mejor agrega la dependencia en el archivo build.gradle de tu proyecto, revisa mi respuesta.

Comment: si igual ya lo tenia en el Gradle pero ni asi y no se por que me tomo solo asi